# Which event captures position change of a Window?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, events, window

I need some event like the SizeChanged on MainWindow that is activated when the user has changed the position of a window?

Any ideas?

Many Thanks,

Comment: Doh. So obvious. I was keep looking for Position instead of location :))

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think it is the [`LocationChanged` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.locationchanged.aspx).

Answer (score 8):

LocationChanged?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.locationchanged.aspx

Answer (score 5):

I believe that `.LocationChanged` is the event you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

How to Find an Event - A Visual Studio Adventure

[image: Step1]

[image: Step2]

Answer (score 1):

You can even try RegionChanged event which is similar to LocationChanged